# Can i take a small vibtaror with me to Kuwait without the battery?

Tags: international-travel, kuwait, sex

I'm travelling from Australia to kuwait and wanted to know if it's possible for me to travel with a vibrator, without the battery and unscrewing the cap and just tucking different parts of it in a piece of clothing.
I'm not even going to try travelling with the handcuffs, pretty sure that's not discreet at all.

Comment: If you hide bits of your dismantled item around your luggage it might prompt the Kuwaitis to wonder what else you're hiding.

Comment: I'm with Arthur on this. Having several parts of a dismantled electronic device hidden in clothing would invite security concerns. Is it a detonator? or something equally nefarious? If I were you, I'd just buy a hand massager instead (and remove the batteries while it's in your luggage).